# I have a problem viewing the layout on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

I'll try to be brief.
When I start my app on some devices I have problems in the arrangement of the CardView.
I think this happens with older devices. I add below the images, in the first two the problem does not exist, in the other two yes.

I tried everything, in Android studio it shows correctly with all the APIs (20-29)
the java code has not been changed.

**Samsung j5 2016:**
[image]

**Xiaomi Redmi 5 Plus:**
[image]

**Tablet Lenovo:**
[image]

**Wiko Rainbow lite:**
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dracula"
    tools:context=".Capitoli">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:text="hi"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text"
                android:text="58 "
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="62dp"
                android:layout_height="62dp"
                android:src="@drawable/tomato"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <GridLayout
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:rowCount="3"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/whale"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:textColor="@color/viola"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:text="capitolo 1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/whale"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:textColor="@color/viola"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:text="capitolo 1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Welcome to community. I suggest you to re-write your xml code with using ConstraintLayout using percentages or LinearLayout with weight attributes.

Comment: Try to use `android:layout_width="0dp"` in each `CardView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Please try with following code. I have updated it. please try with this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    tools:context=".Capitoli">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="hi"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:text="58 "
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="62dp"
                android:layout_height="62dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/whale" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="capitolo 1"
                        android:textColor="@color/viola"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/whale" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="capitolo 1"
                        android:textColor="@color/viola"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```